# WaitForControlReady() vs WaitForControExist()/WaitForControEnabled()

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

If for a given `UITestControl`, the `WaitForControlExist()` and `WaitForControlEnabled()` methods return true, is it guaranteed that the method `WaitForControlReady()` will also return true?

In other word, are

```
uiItem.WaitForControlExist() && uiItem.WaitForControlEnabled()
```

and

```
uiItem.WaitForControlReady()
```

equivalent?

If not, what is the difference between them and what is the correct way to use them?

Answer (score 4):

WaitForControlReady() waits for the control to be ready to accept any mouse/keyboard inputs. Coded UI playback engine implicitly calls this API for all actions to wait for the control to be ready before doing any operation.

WaitForControlEnabled() – This waits for the control to be enabled.

WaitForControlExist() – This waits for the control to exist on the UI.

Even WaitForControlExist() and WaitForControlEnabled() methods return true WaitForControlReady() may be false because any asynchronize operations may block the control to be ready to receive any inputs.